# Handling of exceptions, do I have to catch each specific exception?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception

Just a thing I've been thinking of for a while. Do I need to handle KeyNotFoundException by catching that specific exception or can I just use a "blank" catch like this:

```
try
{
    //Code goes here
}
catch
{
}
```

Or do I have to do it like this:

```
try
{
    //Code goes here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Or do I have to do it like this:

```
try
{
    //Code goes here
}
catch(KeyNotFoundException ex)
{
}
```

The reason why I ask is that when I look at crash count at App Hub I have a lot of crashes related to "KeyNotFoundException" but I never experience any crashes in my app. Could this be the problem, that I don't catch the specific exception and that App Hub crash statistics classifies it as a crash even if the exception is handled?

EDIT:
Here are some screenshots of the App Hub crash statistics (Stack Trace). Does anyone know ehat in detail it means? It has to do with my background agent and that might be the reason for why I never experience any crashes in my app:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should figure out why the exception is thrown. `TryGetValue` instead of the indexer avoids this exception. The underlying problem might also be multi-threading, in which case adding correct synchronization is the correct fix.

Answer (score 3):

No, the marketplace is counting only unhandled exceptions, so your app does crash.

An empty catch or catching Exceptions are the most general catches (Every exception is derived from the Exception base class, so you're catching everything.), the critical code is somewhere you don't use try-catch. Based on the exception you should check your dictionaries and think about what are the conditions which can cause error.

Generally a good practice is to check the correctness of parameters in your public methods so if any problem occurs you can provide yourself more helpful error messages, for example:

```
public User GetUser(string username)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        throw ArgumentNullException("username");
    return this.users[username];
}
```

In this case if things goes wrong you will see that you used a null for username, otherwise you would see a KeyNotFoundException. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Ok, thanks. Since I never experence any crashes I think it has to do with the background agent. When lloking at the traces it mentions OnInvoke: http://i44.tinypic.com/auv4tu.jpg

Comment: The stack trace saying you are trying to access a non existing isolated storage settings entry from your background agent. Maybe after reinstalling your application you can reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a base exception to catch a more derived exception, so `Exception` will catch `KeyNotFoundException` because the latter inherits the former. So strictly speaking, if you want to catch "any" exception, `catch (Exception)` will suffice.

However, you should only catch exceptions if you can handle them in some meaningful manner. Though I'm not sure how this mindset stacks up against WP development.

As for your underlying problem, I've no idea. Does the App Hub not provide any details around the crash such as stack traces?

Your best bet is to leave the template code in place that registers for the unhandled exceptions event and put some logging into your application to record as much detail as you can about the state of the app during the crash.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a fast reply. So my first example above is wrong, I need to specify catch(Exception Ex)?

Comment: @John - no, you do not. Your first example is fine. See the linked C# documentation in my answer ;-)

Comment: @All I'm not going to be the one suggesting to catch all exceptions lol, it's the last thing I would do, though it is technically correct in terms of the question being asked.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth Thank you! When I look at the stack trace I see this: http://i44.tinypic.com/auv4tu.jpg  Does that tell you anything? Just an unhandled exception?

Comment: @John It only tells me that something somewhere is trying to get a key that doesn't exist, whether it's in your code or the Isolated Storage code I'm not sure. Update your question with that link.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have to catch each specific exception type in a try / catch block, see the [C# language reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28VS.80%29.aspx).

However, rather than wrapping all your code in try / catch blocks, you probably want to add exception handling logic and logging into a handler for the [Application.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28VS.95%29.aspx) event. See [this excellent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) for an example of how to handle this event.

Comment: Thank you, then I just need to figure out why my I have so many crashes in App Hub: http://i44.tinypic.com/auv4tu.jpg Looks like my OnInvoke function is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a specific exception, such as `KeyNotFoundException` in a particular part of the code then you catch it like this

```
try
{
    //Code goes here
}
catch(KeyNotFoundException ex)
{

}
```

If you want to catch a specific exception and some undefined one you do something like this

```
try
{
    //Code goes here
}
catch(KeyNotFoundException ex)
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

If you want to make sure your application doesn't crash use Collin's example with the Application.UnhandledException event.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch all exceptions by catching the base class, but whether you want to depends on what your trying to achieve.

Generally speaking, you should only catch an exception at a level at which you have the knowledge to decide what should be done about the error, ie roll back some action, or display a message to the user. It is often the case that at a certain level it makes sense to catch a specific exception type, as that level of code understands what that means, but it may not make sense to catch all.

Avoid catching everything too soon, exceptions exist to tell you somethings wrong, blanket catching ignores that and can mean your program keeps running, but starts behaving wrong, possibly corrupting data. Its often better to "fail early and fail fast" when receiving unexpected exceptions.

Comment: @ Foo42, yes I know. I'll try to handle specific errors to make the app better. It's really frustrating to see the crash statistics but never see any crashes ehen using the app :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said - No - you dont *need* to catch the specific exception, catching Exception or just catch will prevent the exception from bubbling up.

However you *should* just catch specific exceptions where possible to make your code more explicit in what it is doing.  Better again test for correctness before the potential error condition - again this is covered in other posts.

For your specific problem the link you posted seems to indicate that it is a problem with reading values from the isolated storage (IsolatedStorage.get_Item) - so wherever you access IsolatedStorage during from the ScheduledTaskAgent invocation you need to ensure the item exists before getting it.   Perhaps there are some config settings missing or something?

Comment: Okay, thanks for looking at the links. So basically it should be when reading values? I read some configuration values and I see now that some of them dont have try/catch. So basically I will assign the default value for the specific configuration setting in the catch part and this way it should work. I will update my code and see how it works.

Comment: I would be inclined to use TryGetValue or ContainsKey to check first rather than catching an exception.  But if you find the try/catch more readable then go that way - it is largely a matter of personal preference (since there are not really any performance implications in this example)